# Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample

Tags: php, database, quickbooks

I am trying to connect PHP with quickbooks but I get this error when I click customerQuery.php file in _Sample folder.

ERROR:
Please add realm to App.Config before running this sample.

I have given realmid in app.config and customerquery.php file. But still get this error.

Is anyone know anything about this error.

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Realm Id means your quickbooks company ID which you will get when you authorize the app when you will get the Oauth token and Oauth secret token. So before using Quickbook Online REST API, you need to set the REALMID first.

If you want Company ID (Realm Id) from GUI, then login in to your company.
Click on upper right corner settings button and then click on Your account.

**Setttings Icon ->Your account**

You will find the company ID over there. which is your realm Id and after that you need to pass this ID for every REST API call request.